# Why won't my $_SESSION variable change for each field

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm having a spot of trouble with a basic login script I'm making for a project.
The Login works except for one thing that I can't get around:

At the top of my `User.php`page I have the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['email']){
header("location:Login");
}
?>
```

Which works fine, but my other script for logging in I have this and

**the $_SESSION just does not seem to be initializing or registering, am I doing something fundamentally wrong?**

*Not showing the database details, but they're before this part*

```
// username and password sent from form 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$pass=$_POST['pass']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$email = stripslashes($email);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"; 
$_SESSION['fname'] =$row['fname'];
$_SESSION['lname'] =$row['lname'];
$_SESSION['email'] =$_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['id'] =$_POST['id']; 

$sow = $row['id'];
header("location:User.php?id=$sow");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Is there a session start in your second file? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Within the Login file? No I didn't put one in because I didn't think it was necessary, should I have?

Comment: every page thats not being included and has session usage there should be an session_start() else the script doesnt know sessions

Comment: Yeah the session_start() was the problem! Thank you guys, big help :D